# It is saying missing left parenthesis

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

```
CREATE Table orders(order_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
customer_id INT, 
amount INT, 
address_id varchar(50), 
order_date DATE, 
product_id INT, 
quantity INT, 
FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id), 
FOREIGN KEY(address_id) REFERENCES address(address_id), 
FOREIGN KEY product(product_id) REFERENCES product(product_id));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you change the last foreign key syntax?

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE orders
  2  (
  3     order_id      INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  4     customer_id   INT,
  5     amount        INT,
  6     address_id    VARCHAR2 (50),
  7     order_date    DATE,
  8     product_id    INT,
  9     quantity      INT,
 10     FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers (customer_id),
 11     FOREIGN KEY (address_id)  REFERENCES address   (address_id),
 12     FOREIGN KEY (product_id)  REFERENCES product   (product_id)
 13  );

Table created.

SQL>
```